# I am not able to get all X and Y axis points in nvd3 graph. Am I missing out any options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, linegraph

[image: graph which shows expenditure.]

as graph shown in image I am not able to get all the X and Y intersection points on axis. As well as I want to highlight intersection points with dark circle. Help will be appreciated

code to fill the chart is:
options :
`chart: {
        type: 'lineChart',
        height: 300,
        margin : {
            top: 120,
            right: 100,
            bottom: 40,
            left: 100
        },
        x: function(d){ return d.x; },
        y: function(d){ return d.y; },
        useInteractiveGuideline: false,
        tooltips: false,
        xAxis: {
            tickFormat: function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)); 
            },
            showMaxMin: false

        },
        yAxis: {
            tickFormat: function(d) {
                return '$' + d3.format('.0f')(d) 
            }
        },
    }`

```
var dates = [new Date('12/1/2017'),new Date('12/2/2017'),new Date('12/3/2017'),new Date('12/4/2017'),new Date('12/5/2017')];
var spend = [22, 14, 13, 11, 12];
data = genrateData();
function generateData() {
    var dailySpend = [];                
    for(var i=0; i < dates.length; i++){
        dailySpend.push({x: dates[i], y: spend[i]})
    }
    return [
        {
            values: dailySpend,
            key: 'Daily Spend'
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Post some code, like yoru data to fill the graph and the options

Comment: @AndréBastos I have added data to fill my graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got an answer.

Actually I have removed grid lines from css by giving `.tick` class a `display: none` property, which also removed points from the graph.

If want to remove ONLY grid lines then edit the css by adding property `display: none` to `.tick line` class.